# Renaming test results of UITestActionLog files or folders as the test case name

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, file-rename, ui-testing, test-reporting

Really appreciate your help Adrian. I was able to add the .settingfile, how can I change the generated folder name as the testcase name , lets say I have my testcase as test1(){} I want the result folder to be named as test1 as well?

I Select the option on the general tab and define the User_defined Scheme , but what ever I write there appears on my test result folder, I want it to be the name of my test case

---

In coded UI, we need to rename the test result `UITestActionLog` files or folders to be the same as the test case name.

Let's say my test case name is `test1(){}`, and I would like to be able to see the test result file as `test1` as well. I don't see the test setting window opening when selecting the test setting file, so I'm not sure where it is suggested to add this code:

```
FileName= testContext.ResultsDirectory + "\" + testContext.TestName.ToString()+".extension".
```

Comment: Double clicking (to **Open**) the `.testsettings` file should open a window within which the **General** section allows the test log files to be named.

Comment: I cant add a .testsetting file from the solution, there is no testsetting file in new items, so i tried to add an existing one but apparently its not opening the general window, this is very argent for me do you have any suggestions i can add a testsetting file in vs 2012 premium coded ui?

Comment: You can create a `.testsettings` file using the context menu of the Visual Studio solution, choose **Add**, **New Item**, and then select **Test Settings**.

Comment: Solution explorer has different context menus for different items in the solution. Relevant here, the **Add ...** menus have different entries for the solution and for its projects.