# Renaming the UITestActionLog file to be same as Test Case name

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, file-rename, test-reporting

Hi currently my UITestACtionLog file is not naming after my test case. I have looked in to this post [Renaming test results of UITestActionLog files or folders as the test case name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638517/renaming-test-results-of-uitestactionlog-files-or-folders-as-the-test-case-name) and I am able to add the .settingfile but I have no idea on how to edit the file so that it will change my UITestActionLog name to be same as my Test Case name. When I open the .settingfile it looks like this [image]

I have no idea how to edit in this screen. Would appricate if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Look below the highlighted "General" on the left hand side, where it says "Test results name"; click on that.

Comment: yup i saw that. But the prefix name is only one name? I have 100 cases in one project to run and all are in different naming. @AdrianHHH